# Could someone simply explain how a railgun works?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electricity, charge

Could someone simply explain how a [railgun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) works? What could possibly accelerate an object that fast in such a short distance? I've heard it has to do with current between two rails, but I simply do not understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176396/ also see http://www.wired.com/2014/08/the-physics-of-the-railgun/

Answer (score 2):

The short and simple answer is that [railguns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) utilize a version of the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) with the term $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B}$ as the main driver.  They then take advantage of [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction) when a [paramagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism) material like [aluminium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium) is exposed to a rapidly changing magnetic flux so that the $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B}$-term can impart an impulse on the object/projectile.

The large speed gained in a short distance is accomplished through the use of huge [capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) that discharge very quickly, thus producing a massive $\partial \mathbf{j}/\partial t$ and/or $\partial \mathbf{E}/\partial t$.  Thus, one will have a large change in force in a short period of time, or a large $\partial \mathbf{F}/\partial t$.